# MySQL: Fazer pivot (linhas p/ colunas) de colunas com o resultado de um query dinamicamente

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Eu tenho dois conjuntos de tabelas abaixo:

**1:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Montei uma query que traz o resultados das duas tabelas utilizando `Union`:

```
Select
  tbprojeto.projNome As Projeto,
  tbindp.indPNome As `Tipo(Ind/Idx)`,
  tbindc.indcValor As Valor,
  tbproj_cenario.projCenNome As Cenário,
  tbidxind_grp.idxIndGrpNome As `Grupo de Ánalise`
From
  tbprojeto Inner Join
  tbindp On tbindp.indPProj_Id = tbprojeto.projId Inner Join
  tbindc On tbindc.indcInd_Id = tbindp.indPId Inner Join
  tbproj_cenario On tbproj_cenario.projCenProj_Id = tbprojeto.projId And
    tbindc.indcCen_Id = tbproj_cenario.projCenId Inner Join
  tbidxind_grp On tbindp.indPIdxIndGrp_Id = tbidxind_grp.idxIndGrpId
Union
Select
  tbprojeto.projNome As Projeto,
  tbidxp.idxPNome As `Tipo (Ind/Indx)`,
  tbidxc.IdxCValor As Valor,
  tbproj_cenario.projCenNome As Cenário,
  tbidxind_grp.idxIndGrpNome
From
  tbprojeto Inner Join
  tbidxp On tbidxp.idxPProj_Id = tbprojeto.projId Inner Join
  tbidxc On tbidxc.IdxCIdx_Id = tbidxp.idxPId Inner Join
  tbproj_cenario On tbproj_cenario.projCenProj_Id = tbprojeto.projId And
    tbidxc.IdxCProjCen_Id = tbproj_cenario.projCenId Inner Join
  tbidxind_grp On tbidxp.idxPIdxIndGrp_Id = tbidxind_grp.idxIndGrpId
```

Esse é o resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou tentando fazer o pivot desta query especificamente para que cada valor da coluna cenário seja uma nova coluna com join com a coluna Valor, o resultado seria algo visualmente assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois de muito trabalho e ajuda do pessoal, consegui isso (abaixo) com esse código:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'case when projCenNome = "',
      projCenNome,
      '" then indcValor end AS \'',
      projCenNome, '\''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from (select projCenNome from tbproj_cenario 
        inner join tbindc on tbindc.indcCen_Id = tbproj_cenario.projCenId 
       ) A;

SET @sql = CONCAT('Select  tbindp.`indPNome` As Valor , ', @sql, '
From tbindc
  Inner Join
  tbproj_cenario On tbindc.indcCen_Id = tbproj_cenario.projCenId 
  Inner Join
  tbindp On tbindc.indcInd_Id = tbindp.indPId');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, os valores das outras colunas, no caso Nome, não estão transpostos, assim se repetindo, como poderia contornar isso?

Comment: Hoje de tarde respondi algo semelhante a sua duvida, claro a estrutura não é a mesma, mas tomara que te ajude. Segue o link, o nome desta técnica é `PIVOT`, porém, é feita no modo machão, sem nada de molezinha hehehe... http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/93554/retornar-valores-de-todos-meses-do-ano-extraindo-por-m%C3%AAs/93702#93702

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Editei a resposta para ajudar nessa etapa:**

Coloque um valor zerado, se não tem valor para isso:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'case when projCenNome = "',
      projCenNome,
      '" then indcValor else 0 end AS \'',
      projCenNome, '\''
    )
  ) INTO @sql
from (select projCenNome from tbproj_cenario 
        inner join tbindc on tbindc.indcCen_Id = tbproj_cenario.projCenId 
       ) A;

SET @sql = CONCAT('Select  tbindp.`indPNome` As Valor , ', @sql, '
From tbindc
  Inner Join
  tbproj_cenario On tbindc.indcCen_Id = tbproj_cenario.projCenId 
  Inner Join
  tbindp On tbindc.indcInd_Id = tbindp.indPId WHERE indcValor is not null');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Aqui o exemplo: **http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c9b388/5**

Comment: Bom, você pode criar um loop para isso a partir de uma query só dos tipos, mas não tem outra forma de fazer coluna, a menos que você coloque o nome das colunas como o primeiro valor da sua consulta.

Comment: Só que daí você tem q trazer como valor o nome... e pode fazer uma subquery: `Select 'titulo 1' as campo1, 'titulo 2' as campo2, (select  ... )`

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598120/mysql-pivot-table-query-with-dynamic-columns

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b9d59/2

Comment: Editei, veja lá se funciona

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30290/discussion-between-artur-indio-and-ivan-ferrer).

Comment: Ivan dei uma editada.

Comment: Provavelmente isso esteja acontecendo porque não tem um nome associado a estes valores, faz uma consulta e veja um dos exemplos para ver onde está ocorrendo essa falha.