# Retornar valores de todos meses do ano extraindo por mês

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, postgresql, hql

Estou com o seguinte SELECT:

```sql
SELECT coalesce(sum(vs.total), 0) FROM tabela_exemplo t
WHERE extract(year from t.data_entrada) = extract(year from current_date)
GROUP BY extract(month from t.data_entrada);
```

O que retorna o seguinte resultado:

```
171000.00 -- Referente ao mês de Setembro
21000.00 -- Referente ao mês de Outubro
```

Não existem registros na tabela `tabela_exemplo` referente aos outros meses do ano, porém gostaria de retornar todos os 12 meses do ano a partir desse select com valor igual a 0, apenas para preencher no gráfico e não deixar com que isso seja tratado no servidor Java, mas somente no banco de dados. Exemplo:

```
-- Outro meses antes de Setembro 
171000.00 -- Referente ao mês de Setembro
21000.00 -- Referente ao mês de Outubro
0.00 -- Referente ao mês de Novembro
0.00 -- Referente ao mês de Dezembro
```

Irei fazer utilizando HQL. Por enquanto estou verificando como ficaria o `SELECT` diretamente pelo banco de dados (que no caso é o PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O nome desta técnica é **PIVOT**.

Tente algo semelhante isso com a sua instrução SQL.

```sql
SELECT INFO.CODIGO, INFO.CFILIAL, INFO.ANO,
    SUM(INFO.MES01) AS MES01,
    SUM(INFO.MES02) AS MES02,
    SUM(INFO.MES03) AS MES03,
    SUM(INFO.MES04) AS MES04,
    SUM(INFO.MES05) AS MES05,
    SUM(INFO.MES06) AS MES06 
FROM (
    SELECT
        TAB.CODIGO, TAB.CFILIAL, TAB.ANO,
        CASE WHEN TAB.MES = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -5, GETDATE())) THEN SUM(TAB.VALOR_TOTAL) ELSE 0 END AS MES06,
        CASE WHEN TAB.MES = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -4, GETDATE())) THEN SUM(TAB.VALOR_TOTAL) ELSE 0 END AS MES05,
        CASE WHEN TAB.MES = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) THEN SUM(TAB.VALOR_TOTAL) ELSE 0 END AS MES04,
        CASE WHEN TAB.MES = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -2, GETDATE())) THEN SUM(TAB.VALOR_TOTAL) ELSE 0 END AS MES03,
        CASE WHEN TAB.MES = MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())) THEN SUM(TAB.VALOR_TOTAL) ELSE 0 END AS MES02,
        CASE WHEN TAB.MES = MONTH(GETDATE()) THEN SUM(TAB.VALOR_TOTAL) ELSE 0 END AS MES01

    FROM (
        SELECT 
            MONTH(NFSAIDA.DATA) AS MES, YEAR(NFSAIDA.DATA) AS ANO,
            CLIENTES.CODIGO, CLIENTES.CFILIAL, NOTAFISCALSAIDA.VALOR_TOTAL + NOTAFISCALSAIDA.DESPESAS AS VALOR_TOTAL
        FROM NOTAFISCALSAIDA                                      
            INNER JOIN CLIENTES ON (NOTAFISCALSAIDA.CODIGO = CLIENTES.CODIGO AND NOTAFISCALSAIDA.CFILIAL = CLIENTES.CFILIAL)
        WHERE CLIENTES.CODIGO BETWEEN 0 AND 999

    ) AS TAB
    GROUP BY TAB.CODIGO, TAB.CFILIAL, TAB.ANO, TAB.MES
) AS INFO
GROUP BY INFO.CODIGO, INFO.CFILIAL, INFO.ANO
GROUP BY INFO.CODIGO, INFO.CFILIAL, INFO.ANO
```