# Como transformar linhas em colunas, quando o número de linhas é variável em R

Tags: r

Tenho um Data Frame dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E preciso que ele fique dessa forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A variável que define a coluna pode ser calculada conforme  a imagem abaixo 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A sequencia se inicia a cada mudança do id, no excel seria fácil mas eu quero aprender a fazer isso no R.

Comment: William, bem vindo ao SOpt. Por que você precisa dos dados neste formato? No padrão do R, as colunas representam variáveis, e as linhas observações. Se o número de `COD_pr` varia para cada `ID`, provavelmente o melhor seria deixar no formato que já está e trabalhar assim. Outra possibilidade seria juntar todos em uma coluna, mas não é uma organização agradável. Fazer o que você quer é possível, mas provavelmente vai te gerar problemas no futuro, pois aparentemente suas colunas não tem um significado real.

Comment: William, está faltando a variável que indica em que coluna colocar o `COD_pr`, fornecendo essa variável é simples fazer o que você quer, conforme resposta abaixo.

Comment: William, coloquei uma resposta que calcula a coluna segundo a mudança de ID e depois passa o data.frame para o formato wide.

Comment: O nome disso é pivot, [veja esta resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/92456/mysql-fazer-pivot-linhas-p-colunas-de-colunas-com-o-resultado-de-um-query-di/92464#92464)

Answer (score 3):

William,o  que você quer fazer é passar o data.frame do formato *long* para o formato *wide*.

Construindo a variável `col` conforme a mudança de ID, ficaria da seguinte forma.

Reproduzindo seu data.frame original:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(rep(313721, 3),
                        rep(313718, 2),
                        rep(313729, 6)),
                 COD_pr = c(205073,
                            176779,
                            191991,
                            198089,
                            201429,
                            167489,
                            119926,
                            170093,
                            170363,
                            123486,
                            158028))
```

Calculando a coluna segundo a mudança de ID.

```
df$col <- unlist(sapply(rle(df$ID)$lengths, seq, from = 1))
```

Passando o data.frame para o formato wide.

```
library(tidyr)
spread(df, col, COD_pr)
      ID      1      2      3      4      5      6
1 313718 198089 201429     NA     NA     NA     NA
2 313721 205073 176779 191991     NA     NA     NA
3 313729 167489 119926 170093 170363 123486 158028

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID~col, value.var = "COD_pr")
      ID      1      2      3      4      5      6
1 313718 198089 201429     NA     NA     NA     NA
2 313721 205073 176779 191991     NA     NA     NA
3 313729 167489 119926 170093 170363 123486 158028
```

***Resposta anterior***

Entretanto, no exemplo que você deu, faltaria a variável "col", isto é, precisamos saber como definir em que coluna cada variável COD_pr entra para podermos distribuir os valores da forma que você quer.

Supondo que essa variável "col" exista, é fácil fazer isso tanto com o `tidyr` quanto com o `reshape2`. Veja este exemplo ilustrativo, similar aos seus dados:

```
set.seed(10)
df <- data.frame(ID = rep(c(1,2,3), 4),
                 col = c(rep("col1", 3), 
                         rep("col2", 2),
                         rep("col3", 1), 
                         rep("col4", 1),
                         rep("col5", 2),
                         rep("col6", 3)),
                 COD_pr = rnorm(12))


library(tidyr)
spread(df, col, COD_pr)
  ID        col1       col2      col3      col4      col5       col6
1  1  0.01874617 -0.5991677        NA -1.208076        NA -0.2564784
2  2 -0.18425254  0.2945451        NA        NA -0.363676  1.1017795
3  3 -1.37133055         NA 0.3897943        NA -1.626673  0.7557815

library(reshape2)
dcast(df, ID~col, value.var = "COD_pr")
  ID        col1       col2      col3      col4      col5       col6
1  1  0.01874617 -0.5991677        NA -1.208076        NA -0.2564784
2  2 -0.18425254  0.2945451        NA        NA -0.363676  1.1017795
3  3 -1.37133055         NA 0.3897943        NA -1.626673  0.7557815
```